# Ritz method for the buckling of a plate using calculus of variation

Tags: numerical-methods, calculus-of-variations, numerical-optimization

I need to find buckling of plate. And i have got the constant in analytical solution which can be founded from variation methods.
How can i find polynomial for the same function for Ritz method? I really don't understand explanations from books.